# Reading characters in from a string in c++

Tags: c++, input, filestream

I am trying to take an input file and read it into an array letter by letter.  The main idea is that I am trying to count how many occurrences of each letter of the alphabet there are keeping in mind that a and A are different letters. I dont think this is probably the best method of doing so but its just how my mind is trying to work the problem out.

**My attempt:**

```
#include "hw05.h"
int main() {
const int MAX =  10000; //trying to figure out how to dynamically
                        //allocate this to cooperate with any file
ifstream inFile;
string file;
char fileAr[MAX];
int index;
index = 0;
size = 0;

inFile.open("hw05data.txt");
while (inFile) {
    inFile.get(fileAr[index]);
    index++;
}
cout << fileAr[10] << endl; //this is just to check if its working
inFile.close();
return 0; 
}
```

Basically I would like to know how to take a file and grab letter by letter from it and count the occurrences for each one.

Comment: Does that code work or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Counting letters from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899198/c-counting-letters-from-a-file)

Comment: Array of 256 Elements will allow you to count all possible characters (except the Anti Paladin because they lie about their character code. Chaotic Evil you know) in a standard 8 bit character set. So read a character, use it as the array index, increment that index, and only print the indexes you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Try using map container. It takes care  allocation and counts letter occurrences.